# Help with MongoDB and unique id generation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js

Right now we're doing all of our unique id generation by using MongoDB's baked in ids. We have some instances where we need to create an id for a object before we add anything to the database.

We could create an entry get the id and then delete the entry if we end up never needing it, but I would rather not put that load on the system for such an easy task. Is there any way to be in sync with mongos native methods for doing this without putting unnecessary load on the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty simply to do. With the exception of upsert operations the ObjectId is client side generated. In other words, when you perform a save operation from within your app the driver will automatically do (pseudo):

```
if(!doc.containsKey("_id"))
    doc.put(_id, new ObjectId());
```

So all you have to do is generate an ObjectId yourself, do whatever you need to do with it and then set the _id of your document to that value rather than have the mongo driver do it for you.

Note that this is **exactly** as safe as having the driver generated the IDs. ObjectIds are designed to eliminate ID collisions (read: make it unlikely to the point of collisions becoming irrelevant). Also, the time between generating the id and storing it also does not introduce ID collision issues.

If you **save** a document with an _id that already exists in the database it will overwrite the original document with that _id.

If you **insert** a document with an _id that already exists you will get a duplicate _id error (error 11000).

Comment: So just by generating a new ObjectId I can `collection.insert` normally without worrying about anything? Do I need to make sure `_id:` doesn't become a primitive string along the way? What would happen if I inserted a doc with the same `_id` as another? Thanks for the info!

Comment: Yes, generating your own _id and then doing insert is exactly what a save operation without an _id does. You need to make sure it stays an ObjectId (which it will). I'll edit my answer to cover your last point.

Comment: Passing it in and out of Redis was the process I was worried about that would parse it to a primitive string.

Comment: I understand but you can guard against that in your app since it'll touch your app between Redis and MongoDB I assume.

Comment: Will this perserve continuity as far as the the inherent dating built into mongo?

Comment: No, again, there is no practical difference between you generating the OID and the driver doing it. Timestamp baked into the OID will be your client's local time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Bson ObjectIds as the ids in your database (see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs ).  You are free to generate your own.  The C# driver provides a way to generate ObjectIds client-side.  What javascript driver are you using to call MongoDB?  Does it not have a call to generate a new ObjectId?

Comment: I'm using the mongo-native driver. There is something called "Primary Key Factories" but I'm not sure if that's what I need since it still generates them during db calls.

Comment: I know I can pass in my own ids but I don't know how to do this with 100% certainty that I won't collide with ids generated by mongo.

Comment: All ObjectIds are generated client side with the exception of upsert which will do it server side.